# How to add a classname in React Js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Im trying to add a classname to the nav bar when the user scroll down. I did this:

```
var myNav = document.getElementById("nav");

window.onscroll = function() {
  "use strict";
  if (document.body.scrollTop >= 150 || document.documentElement.scrollTop >= 150) {
    myNav.classList.add("scroll");
  } else {
    myNav.classList.remove("scroll");
  }
};
```

But it gave me an error:

```
Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList')
```

I don't know why :(

Answer (score 4):

You're getting that error because no element with that id exists. Perhaps it doesn't exist *yet*, or perhaps it never exists. But either way, I recommend you avoid mixing react with direct manipulation of the dom. The react way to do this is to listen for the scroll in a useEffect, and then set state:

```
const NavBar = () => {
  const [scroll, setScroll] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleScroll = () => {
      setScroll(document.body.scrollTop >= 150 || document.documentElement.scrollTop >= 150);
    }
    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div id="nav" className={scroll ? "scroll" : undefined}>

    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works perfect!